# How do you horizontally center a table inside a RelativeLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with a header, scrollable content in the center, and a footer.

The footer is a TableLayout that contains two rows.

The problem is that the rows are always aligned to the left of the screen, but I would like to have the entire table centered horizontally.

I've been working with this all day and can't seem to figure it out.  I've tried to center it using various gravity attributes, but the table is always aligned to the left.

Here is a picture:

http://postimg.org/image/jr40dopzj/

You can see how the TableLayout in the footer is left-aligned horizontally.

Here is the code I have now:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- Header -->
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/header"    
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#FC9" >

            <!-- "Label1:" and editText1 -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Label 1:"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label1"
                android:ems="8"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </EditText>

            <!-- "Label 2:" and editText2 -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/label1"
                android:paddingTop="26dp"
                android:text="Label 2:"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label2"
                android:ems="8"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout> 
        <!-- End header -->


        <!-- Footer -->
        <!-- I cannot center this TableLayout horizontally. -->
        <!-- It is always aligned to the left. -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#FFF" >

           <TableRow
               android:weightSum="7"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelA"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Aaa" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelB"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Bbb" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelC"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Ccc" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelD"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Ddd" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Eee" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelF"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Fff" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelG"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Ggg" />
           </TableRow>

           <TableRow
               android:weightSum="7"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxA"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxB"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxC"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxD"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxF"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxG"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true" />    
           </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
        <!-- End footer -->

    <!-- Scrollable content in middle of screen -->
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:background="#005" >

    </ScrollView>
    <!-- End scrollable content -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try changing orientation for table layout to horizontal

Comment: It's still aligned to the left.

Comment: you want all the textboxes to be in straight vertical line???and center aligned

Comment: You might try adding `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to your footer `TableLayout `.

Comment: @KaranMer No, I am only concerned about the footer, which contains two rows - one row of TextViews and a row below that of CheckBoxes.  I am trying to make that entire table in the footer horizontally aligned in the center.  Right now the table is 'stuck' to the left side of the screen.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, but I already tried that.  It's still stuck to the left of the screen.

Comment: try setting android:gravity="center"

Comment: @KaranMer I already tried that too and it's still stuck to the left of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way hope this will help you...
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Header -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FC9" >

        <!-- "Label1:" and editText1 -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Label 1:"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/label1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label1"
            android:ems="8"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </EditText>

        <!-- "Label 2:" and editText2 -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label1"
            android:layout_below="@id/label1"
            android:paddingTop="26dp"
            android:text="Label 2:"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/label2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/editText1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label2"
            android:ems="8"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- End header -->


    <!-- Footer -->
    <!-- I cannot center this TableLayout horizontally. -->
    <!-- It is always aligned to the left. -->

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FFF" >

        <TableRow
            android:weightSum="7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelA"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Aaa" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelB"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Bbb" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelC"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Ccc" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelD"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Ddd" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelE"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Eee" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelF"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Fff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelG"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Ggg" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:weightSum="7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxA"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:checked="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxB"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:checked="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxC"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:checked="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxD"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:checked="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxE"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:checked="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxF"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:checked="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBoxG"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:checked="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
    <!-- End footer -->

    <!-- Scrollable content in middle of screen -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:background="#005" >

    </ScrollView>
    <!-- End scrollable content -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That works! So basically, you are centering each component of each row by placing each of them within their own LinearLayout.

Comment: yes becz if you gave equal weight to all "CheckBox" and set gravity="center" but "CheckBox" have text on right side so we have to set "CheckBox" width "wrap_content" and gave gravity="center their parent layout" with equal weight.

Comment: I noticed that when I add a long vertical list of widgets to the center ScrollView such that they overflow and force the scrollbar to appear, the TextViews in the footer ("Aaa", "Bbb", "Cdd", etc.) become "A", "B", "C", etc.  For some reason, some of the text is disappearing.  This doesn't occur with Rahul's solution.

Comment: i have test with your case but it not happens with me so can you please let me know which device have you try to test ?

Comment: The physical device I tested it on is an HTC Evo 3D (4.3 in. screen, 540x960 pixels, Android 4.0.3).

Answer (score 2):

try this answer

with out adding more layout to xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Header -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FC9" >

    <!-- "Label1:" and editText1 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label 1:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label1"
        android:ems="8"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </EditText>

    <!-- "Label 2:" and editText2 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label1"
        android:paddingTop="26dp"
        android:text="Label 2:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label2"
        android:ems="8"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- End header -->


<!-- Footer -->
<!-- I cannot center this TableLayout horizontally. -->
<!-- It is always aligned to the left. -->

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7" ><!-- I have made change here -->

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="7" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelA"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" <!--set Gravity -->
            android:text="Aaa"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelB"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bbb"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelC"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ccc"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelD"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ddd"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelE"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Eee"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Fff"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelG"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ggg"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="7" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxA"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxB"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxC"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxD"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxE"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxG"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="true" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<!-- End footer -->


<!-- Scrollable content in middle of screen -->

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:background="#005"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
</ScrollView>
<!-- End scrollable content -->
```

Comment: For some reason the checkboxes are not centered horizontally.  They are still more to the left of the screen.

Comment: I fixed it.  For each of the CheckBoxes, I changed android:gravity="center" to android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"